# Joint probability distribution of X and Y using a table, where

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Suppose two 4 sided dices are rolled. X is the sum of two resulting numbers after rolling the dice. Y is the absolute difference of two resulting numbers after rolling the dice.

X sample set is {2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
and Y sample set is {0,1,2,3}

I have calculated the values of X which are : 
F(2) = [(1,1)] = 1/16
F(3) = [(1,2), (2,1)] = 2/16
F(4) = [(1,3), (2,2), (3,1)] = 3/16
F(5) = 4/16
F(6) = 3/16
F(7) = 2/16
F(8) = 1/16

For Y following are the values:
F(0) = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)] = 4/16
F(1) = 6/16
F(2) = 4/16
F(3) = 2/16

Please help me in finding joint probability distribution of X and Y using a table. I am confused which values shall I consider?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: @farruhota : Thank you. But I am confused about how to make Joint Probability Distribution table?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos : Thank you. I have edited the question and added more details to it.

Comment: Nice start. Thanks for the additional info.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The table of favorable outcomes:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
X/Y&0&1&2&3\\
\hline
2&(1,1)&\emptyset&\emptyset&\emptyset\\
\hline
3&\emptyset&(1,2),(2,1)&\emptyset&\emptyset\\
\hline
4&(2,2)&\emptyset&(1,3),(3,1)&\emptyset\\
\hline
5&\emptyset&(2,3),(3,2)&\emptyset&(1,4),(4,1)\\
\hline
6&(3,3)&\emptyset&(2,4),(4,2)&\emptyset\\
\hline
7&\emptyset&(3,4),(4,3)&\emptyset&\emptyset\\
\hline
8&(4,4)&\emptyset&\emptyset&\emptyset\\
\end{array}$$
The contingency table:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
X/Y&0&1&2&3\\
\hline
2&1&0&0&0\\
\hline
3&0&2&0&0\\
\hline
4&1&0&2&0\\
\hline
5&0&2&0&2\\
\hline
6&1&0&2&0\\
\hline
7&0&2&0&0\\
\hline
8&1&0&0&0\\
\end{array}$$
The joint probability table:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
X/Y&0&1&2&3\\
\hline
2&1/16&0&0&0\\
\hline
3&0&2/16&0&0\\
\hline
4&1/16&0&2/16&0\\
\hline
5&0&2/16&0&2/16\\
\hline
6&1/16&0&2/16&0\\
\hline
7&0&2/16&0&0\\
\hline
8&1/16&0&0&0\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

**Comment** not answer. I am doing this for ***six-sided*** dice. In order to give you an informal view of the joint distribution
of $X$ and $Y,$ I did a simulation (in R) of 10,000 performances of the two-die experiment.

In the figure below the probabilities are at the *centers* of the squares.
Points are 'jittered' (randomly displaced) in order to give a clue the relative
frequency with which each $(x,y)$ value occurs. The six points (smeared into squares) at the bottom are less likely than the others.

```
m = 10^4
a = sample(1:6, m, rep=T);  b = sample(1:6, m, rep=T)
x = a+b;  y = abs(a-b)
jx = runif(m, -.4, .4);  jy = runif(m, -.4, .4) # jittering
plot(x+jx, y+jy, pch=".")
  abline(v=2:12, col="green2")
  abline(h=0:5, col="green2")
```

[image]

The probability of each point is a multiple of $1/36.$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer